# Electron - Sending Sysex message via the Web MIDI API crashes renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-midi, sysex

I'm working on an Electron app that can send sysex (system exclusive) MIDI messages to a MIDI device and every time I try to send the sysex message, the renderer crashes. I can send non-sysex messages (noteOn, noteOff, etc..) to the device without issue.

Here's a bit of what i'm doing:

```
message = [240, 126, 127, 6, 1, 247]; // device ID request
outputPort = midi.outputs.get(portID);
outputPort.send(message);
```

In the web browser, Chrome only, you need to have a secure connection and request user permission to be able to send sysex messages. I'm wondering if these two Web MIDI sysex requirements are causing this crash as I'm unclear on how to satisfy these conditions in the context of an Electron app.

Comment: This was confirmed to be a bug with Electron. The Electron team promptly resolved the issue and sending sysex works as it should. Here's the github issue thread: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2669

Comment: Voting to close this as it can't be reproduced - the bug was fixed four years ago.